How change Angularjs CKEditor with custom directive and ng-ckeditor for ckeditor 4.24.0 version
I found Angularjs CKEditor Example with custom directive and ng-ckeditor in this link but this example work only until ckeditor 4.22.1 version and not work with ckeditor 4.24.0.
https://codepen.io/navin_sh/pen/RKQweE
cdn.ckeditor.com/4.22.1/standard/ckeditor.js
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.3/angular.js

Ckeditor tell older version befor ckeditor 4.24.0 have security issue and i want use latest version.
What changes should I make in this script so that it can work with version 4.24.0?

Try switching to the latest version (4.9.2) of ckEditor, which you can find on cdnjs.
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.9.2/ckeditor.js" integrity="sha512-OF6VwfoBrM/wE3gt0I/lTh1ElROdq3etwAquhEm2YI45Um4ird+0ZFX1IwuBDBRufdXBuYoBb0mqXrmUA2VnOA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

Codepen Demo

lateset version is 4.24.0
